# 10 Posiciones aleatorias en una matriz sumando los numeros a su alrededor

Tags: c#, array, random

Saludos cordiales a todos ,tengo un problema al tratar de elegir 10 posisciones aleatorias en una matriz ,las escogo pero las posiciones se repiten ,despues de escoger debo hacer una sumatoria de los elementos que esten alrededor la posicion escogida.

De la siguiente manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi avance

```
namespace PRUEBA
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            
        {
            int[,]matriz= generar(10,10);
            mostrar(matriz);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,20);
            posiciones(matriz);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        
        static int[,] generar ( int f , int c){
            int[,]a= new int[f,c];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= a.GetUpperBound(1); j++) {
                    
                    a[i,j]=r.Next(1,15);
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
        
        static void mostrar ( int[,]a){
            
                
            
            
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= a.GetUpperBound(1); j++) {
                    
                    Console.SetCursorPosition((j*5)+45,(i*2)+12);
                    Console.WriteLine(a[i,j]);
                }
            }
            
        }
        static void posiciones ( int[,]a){
            int num=1;
            while(num <= 10)
            {
            Random r = new Random();
            
            int fila = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0));
            int columna=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1));
            
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila +columna);
            Console.WriteLine(a[fila,columna]);
            num++;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los vecinos de una celda se corresponden a un desplazamiento en vertical y horizontal:

| Offsets |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h: `-1` v: `-1` | h: `0` v: `-1` | h: `1` v: `-1` |
| h: `-1` v: `0` | h: `0` v: `0` | h: `1` v: `0` |
| h: `-1` v: `1` | h: `0` v: `1` | h: `1` v: `1` |

Crea un objeto para almacenar coordenadas:

```
class Coordenada
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
};
```

Con el objeto `Coordenada` puedes redactar una función que calcule la suma de los vecinos de una celda:

```
static void mostrar(int[,] matriz, Coordenada posicion)
{
    Coordenada[] offsets = new Coordenada[8]
    {
        new Coordenada{x = -1, y = -1}, new Coordenada{x = 0, y = -1}, new Coordenada{x = 1, y = -1},
        new Coordenada{x = -1, y =  0},                                new Coordenada{x = 1, y =  0},
        new Coordenada{x = -1, y =  1}, new Coordenada{x = 0, y =  1}, new Coordenada{x = 1, y =  1},
    };

    int suma = 0;
    foreach (Coordenada offset in offsets)
    {
        Coordenada vecino = new Coordenada{x = offset.x + posicion.x, y = offset.y + posicion.y};
        if (vecino.x >= 0 && vecino.x < matriz.GetLength(1) && vecino.y >= 0 && vecino.y < matriz.GetLength(0))
        {
            suma += matriz[vecino.y, vecino.x];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"La suma de los vecinos de la posicion [{posicion.x},{posicion.y}] es {suma}.");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNNb5tAED3DrxhZUYRljEBRpKrEueTQi1tV7aEHxGELa7KS2Y12cQpF@9vd/cCwdqjtAxa8efNm3swUYl0wjo/HgyC0gp@daHCd@n6xR0LAd84qjmq/9z374YUxXmKKSuR76qP3dvi9JwUQ2kALPVS4SUHohzwHu0tQKg1PNKhRAe@MlPAVERqIhqsqshwQr8TSSih6FuZQI4X9hQ1Q/EenzJI4TOI8VRE/EC1ZDXwA7Wuw1ArejnEIbHkbiFP19zSkir7gZotp1bwG8TKF1apVgkZxInWW1M2REkPqNMmyPBuSdWGbKx6PvuG2CZIQksdlagJeGBVsj6NfnDQ4uFv0DuNzHEtY2EBt3nnwllAcGFDqrmqmnEI8sPzQtD2Npte9PoSm@gepWfLC7BP/zNvQSQFvTJCCMDoMYULUcNhup8YoBrsd6FN@cnCmoHViK1oncrbg@DrssG8IQKwy3Pj9X0Czbwlc7wCudwC2A3MAerlBHGpk9syuK0bFKwTOKKzdaudPxo976gS944JQ9mEkRtjSohZW41ij1hYzQJ0LddIsIdlBYLMq5rOqD@7vYfwwexBORHdJ6eYPzzkf48NqM0RlJ144iubjcZgj@Hggd4stsnaWGPZMDExhXqedhqyffJBh73SeAxbQ6xQyWtjLkcfjPw)</kbd>.

Comment: Esta perfecto,pero como lo haria sin utilizar clases ,resulta que aun no estoy familiarizado con eso.

Comment: En lugar de una colección de objetos `Coordenada` puedes tener dos colecciones de enteros con los *offset* vertical/horizontal.

Comment: explendido tratare de hacerlo